# Invariant subspaces of Markov operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ergodic-theory

I am currently working on some kind of graph theoretic problem and the following question came up:

Suppose you have a Markov operator $T$ on $\ell^\infty$, that is a positive, bounded operator such that $T \mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the constant $1$-sequence.

Now suppose that the subspace $c_0$ of sequences coverging to $0$ is $T$-invariant, i.e, $T c_0 \subseteq c_0$. How can this invariance be characterized?

In this setting, one can clearly think of $T$ as a positive infinite matrix such that the sum of each row is equal to $1$. I would suppose that one would have this property if one imposes some kind of decay on the coefficients of the matrix which is uniform for all rows but:

1. I am not sure if that would be a natural condition for the system I am interested in.
2. Such a assertion would be maybe sufficient but is it necessary?

So is their a known characterization for Markov operators on $\ell^\infty$ which leave $c_0$ invariant? I would assume that is a question that turns up naturally in ergodic theory and/or probability theory.

Moreover, one could generalize this question to the more general setting of AM-spaces with unit. Suppose that $T$ is a Markov operator on some AM-space $E$ with unit, that is a positive, bounded operator on $E$ such that $T \mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the unit of $E$. Suppose that $F$ is a closed sublattice such that $TF \subseteq F$.

Is there a useful characterization of the set of Markov operators that leave $F$ invariant?

Comment: Good question! But I have to contradict your claim that "one can clearly think of $T$ as a positive infinite matrix": Let $\varphi \in (\ell^\infty)^*$ denote you favourite Banach limit and define $Tf = \langle \varphi, f \rangle \mathbf 1$ for each $f \in \ell^\infty$. Then $T$ satisfies all your properties, but it cannot be represented as a matrix since it maps all canonical unit vector to $0$.

Comment: Another comment. Even if your operator is represented by a matrix, a decay condition isn’t really going to work for you. For example if the (I,j) entry of the matrix is $2^{-j}$, then the rows decay nicely, but it doesn’t map $c_0$ into $c_0$.

Comment: $T$ preserves $c_0$ if and only if $T e_n \in c_0$ for all n, where $e_n$ is the canonial basis. In case of an infinite matrix, this means that each column tends to 0.